# How to use unidirectional one-to-many mapping relationship?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa

I have an order POJO and an item POJO, the mapping relationship between this two entities are showed as below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ordertable")
public class Order {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="orderid", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "order_item", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "orderId"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "itemId"))
    private Set<Item> items = new HashSet<Item>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name="itemtable")
public class Item {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="itemid", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="title")
    private String title;
}
```

In my database there is a table named order_item:

[image]

It's not allowed me to add another item with same itemId and give me the errors like:

ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'UK_d9fp313gthlw9q6hv0e4aanlm'

ERROR: org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl - HHH000346: Error during managed flush [could not execute statement]

How can I do to make its possible to checkout same item since they are belong to different orders?

Comment: message says that itemid is unique key.

Comment: So do I need to delete the unique property of itemId in the Item POJO?

Comment: How can I to make the itemId in the item_order table not unique?

Comment: it should be changed at the database level.

Comment: OneToMany implies a Items can only be in one order's items list, while you should be using a ManyToMany if the same Item can be in multiple collections.

Comment: ok..I think I have mixed up these concepts and thanks for reminding!!